# Trace Source SQL Server name from received Email

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

One of my client complained that he is receiving an email in every 30 minutes from last 20 days. The sender ID is **TACTaddress** with Subject **XXX formatting completed**. There is no any other information in the email.

I have the Admin access to all the SQL Servers of my company. How can I trace from which server the mail is getting generated?

Comment: Have you checked the email headers? It might tell the IP address.

Comment: How to check the email header? I am using Outlook.

Comment: @Pinwar13 It depends on version, but I'm quite sure google provides you plenty of help how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You could use this view to look up emails sent from your SQL Server:

```
select * from msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems
```

Comment: Wonderful, glad to help! If you feel this helped answer your question, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks! :)